# How would one find out how google would sort a webpage?

Tags: html

So I was told that you can set a certain tag in a html page that will tell search engines what kind of page it is (like if the tag was set to game then google would organize it as game). What tag would this be done in and how would it be found?? (I was told this by older brother so If not possible or is false information I will understand)

Comment: may be the duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704120/what-searching-algorithm-concept-is-used-in-google.

Comment: Google has tons of documentation about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use structured data in your website to tell the search engines what is described on the page and give machine readable details.

This is (at this time) the [recommended way by Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2650907?hl=en).

The format for this is described in great detail on http://schema.org, the types can be found here:

http://schema.org/docs/full.html

To address your example, here is the sample from the type [Game (copy&paste)](http://schema.org/Game):

```html
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Game">
    <section itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <span>Approx. Retail:</span>
        <span itemprop="priceCurrency">$</span><span itemprop="price">17.99</span>
        <a href="/monopoly-2/en_US/shop/where-to-buy.cfm?brand_guid=DAD28866-1C43-11DD-BD0B-0800200C9A66&prodName=Monopoly%20Game" itemprop="availableAtOrFrom">Where To Buy</a>
    </section>
    <span itemprop="audience" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PeopleAudience">
      Ages: <span itemprop="suggestedMinAge">8</span> YEARS & UP
    </span>
      <h4>Game  Description:</h4>
    <p itemprop="description">Own it all as a high-flying trader in the fast-paced world of real estate. Tour the city for the hottest properties: sites, stations and utilities are all up for grabs. Invest in houses and hotels, then watch the rent come pouring in! Make deals with other players and look out for bargains at auction. There are many ways to get what you want. For really speedy dealers, use the speed die for a quick and intense game of Monopoly. So get on Go and trade your way to success!<br/><br/>Includes <span itemprop="gameItem">gameboard</span>, <span itemprop="gameItem">8 tokens</span>, <span itemprop="gameItem">28 Title Deed cards</span>, <span itemprop="gameItem">16 Chance cards</span>, <span itemprop="gameItem">16 Community Chest cards</span>, <span itemprop="gameItem">money pack</span>,<span itemprop="gameItem"> 32 houses</span>, <span itemprop="gameItem">12 hotels</span>, 2 dice and instructions<br/><br/>•Features a speed die for a faster, more intense game<br/>•Includes the new token that was voted No. 1: the cat<br/><br/>For <div itemprop="numberOfPlayers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
<span itemprop="minValue">3</span> to <span itemprop="maxValue">5</span>  players </div>.<br/><br/>Ages 8 and up.<br/><br/>Monopoly and all related characters are trademarks of <span itemprop="copyrightHolder">Hasbro</span>. <P></p>
</section>
```

As you can see there are several attributes like `itemtype`, `itemprop` etc. added that contain the data that is targeted for search engines. These attributes vary from type to type.

Answer (score 0):

Google does a lot more than read tags to organize pages and rank them. However, there is a tag defined in HTML to describe keywords and other information about your page.

Placed in the head of your HTML document, the meta tag can be used to define your pages character set, add a description, keywords and an author (amongst other things).

For example:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="Jordan's Homepage">
<meta name="keywords" content="Games, younger brothers, stack overflow">
<meta name="author" content="Jordan 1591">
</head>
```

Google's ranking algorithms are very complex and not publicly known in their entirety, partly to prevent people from abusing them and being unfairly ranked highly, but any seach engine -including Google - will look at meta tags as a bare minimum.